# Starting Varnish Cache: [FAILED] ... how to debug varnish?

Tags: linux, apache, varnish

I have installed varnish cache . When i try to start or restart i am getting error like

```
Starting Varnish Cache: [FAILED]
```

How can i debug this ? What will be the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Start `varnishlog` and try to start Varnish again. Varnishlog will show you the reason why it doesn't start.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply . there was a porb. in config. now i fixed it

Comment: Great. How do I do this??

Answer (score 1):

try to use `sudo service varnish restart`